# CSS for Hide arrow from select list tag

Tags: css

```
form select.form-control {     -moz-appearance: none; }
```

I am using below css for hiding arrow from select list element but it's not working in Firefox 34 version. is there any css fix for older browser version

https://jsfiddle.net/utLxvqbx/

Comment: adding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) make your question colorful

Comment: See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your css:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/utLxvqbx/2/

Comment: Simply Awesome ! Thanks  a lot.

Comment: For anyone coming to this, it doesn't work on IE11 in VirtualBox VM.